# Insert dict into dataframe with loop

Tags: python, pandas

Fetching data from API with for loop, but only last row is showing. If i put `print` statement instead of `d=`, I get all records for some reason. How to populate a `Dataframe` with all values?

I tried with for loop and with append but keep getting wrong results

```
for x in elements:
    url = "https://my/api/v2/item/" + str(x[number"]) + "/"
    get_data = requests.get(url)
    get_data_json = get_data.json()
    d = {'id': [x["enumber"]], 
         'name': [x["value1"]["name"]],
         'adress': [value2["adress"]],
         'stats': [get_data_json["stats"][5]["rating"]]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.head()
```

Result:

```
id name  order  adress  rating
```

Only last row is showing, probably because it's overwriting until it comes to last element. Should I put another for loop somewhere or there is some obvious solution that I cannot see?

Comment: You need to look into [df.append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) just create the dataframe once before adding all the data then append the new data

Comment: @Jaba generally that is not the way to go. Append the results into a `list` and then use that list to build the data-frame. `.append` with a data-frame is needlessly inefficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put all your data into a list of dictionaries, then convert to a dataframe at the very end

At the top of your code write:

```
all_data = []
```

Then in your loop, after d = {...}, write

```
all_data.append(d)
```

Finally at the end (after the loop has finished)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
```

Comment: thanks, it's populated now, just all values are in `[]`, eg `[3]  [2]  [100]` , how to remove that or it doesn't matter?

Comment: is it because I used these parentheses in [x["entry_number"]] etc?

Comment: @Mr.Mister. It does matter, you should use `x["entry_number"]` instead of `[x["entry_number"]]`, there's no need for the outside brackets `[]`